# How to Open firefox extension page with Selinium

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am trying to automate testing for restful API, and I am using Firefox rest-client extension.
If I type in url box `"chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html"`

This page loaded successfully, however I am unable to open it with `Selenium IDE` or through `Java` code

Here is Selenium code

```
open | chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html
```

or

```
 <tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

It gives me following error

```
[info] Executing: |open | chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html | |
[error] Unexpected Exception: Error: Access to 'chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html' from script denied.
[info] Test case failed
```

I have **noticed** that, It rejects every thing which do not have http:// prefix
Could someone please suggest how to open this extension page so that I can proceed with my Test?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for running standalone chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-window -chrome chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you already have a extension file with .crx extension,if not, you can pack the extension by going in to the developer mode of Chrome.
By using ChromOptions Class you can add particular extension.
Here is the code for chrome, which i wrote and tested. It is working fine in my system.Let me know if you face any issue. Would like to help you.

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Maverick\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Users\\Maverick\\Desktop\\RestClient.crx"));
  WebDriver driver = new  ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html");
```

Comment: I am using firefox browser and there is a plugin in it called "RESTClient, a debugger for restful web services" and URL mentioned above is used to launch the plugin in firefox.